# Combining annotation and filtering in Django for two different classes

Tags: python, django, filter, annotations

Hi I am trying to query and count marketplaces for every infringement only for the logged in user.

Essentially trying to combine these two.

> mar_count =
> Marketplace.objects.annotate(infringement_count=Count('infringement'))
>
> inf=Infringement.objects.filter(groups__user=request.user)

I found a below example but this is for the same class. I have two separate classes. I am a beginner.

> swallow.objects.filter(
> coconuts_carried__husk__color="green" ).annotate(
> num_coconuts=Count('coconuts_carried') ).order_by('num_coconuts')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions) can take a filter as named parameter so:

```
mar_count = Marketplace.objects.annotate(infringement_count=Count('infringement', filter=Q(groups__user=request.user)))
```